# Getting a count of unique values for a column in data frame that end up in each leaf node of Decision Tree?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm building a decision tree model on a dataframe. The dataframe looks something like this:

[image: Sample Dataframe]

I have the plot working fine through this code:

```
from sklearn import tree

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows =1,ncols =1,figsize = (2,2), dpi=600)

tree.plot_tree(clf,
               feature_names = x_pre, 
               filled = True);
```

The code shows me fine how many samples are ending up in each of my leafs.

However, for analysis purposes, I would also like to see how many of the unique ID values in the first column end up in each leaf node of my decision tree.

The manual way i'm doing this right now is to type out each condition of the decision tree for each leaf node and apply it to my dataframe to get the unique ID values in each leaf. Something like this:

```
id_count= df[(df['var2']>=10.5) & (df['var1']='a')]

id_count['ID'].nunique()
```

Since my actual model has a depth of 10 and the actual dataframe has nearly a 100 variables (not all of them utilized by the model ofc), this is quite a lot of work to do especially if the model undergoes changes and iterations.

I was wondering if there is a simpler and faster way to either incorporate the count of unique values for a particular column of the dataframe in each leaf node in the decision tree plot?

Or even just get a count of unique IDs in each unique leaf node without a plot if that's too difficult?

Also, is it possible to get a count of unique IDs in each split as well? For e.g. Var>=10.5 would show 4 unique IDs and Var<=10.5 would show 2 unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

This is my poor man's solution for now that i'm using as a stop gap:

**1.** I turned on the node id feature of the decision tree plot command so that i can see each node id in my plot:

```
from sklearn import tree

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows =1,ncols =1,figsize = (2,2), dpi=600)

tree.plot_tree(clf,
               feature_names = x_pre, 
               filled = True,
               class_names=True,
               node_ids=True);
```

**2.** I have 2 dataframe versions:

a) df3 is the cleaned dataframe with fewer columns that i split into train and test and feed into my model training. df3 does not contain the ID column since it's not needed for model training.

b) df is my original dataframe that i imported as is that contains the unique ID column.

I first removed the target variable from df3 and applied my model on top of it to get node_ids for each row of my dataframe.

```
df4=df3.drop(columns=['TargetVar'])
node_id=clf.apply(df4)
```

I then converted my node_id into a dataframe and merged it with my original dataframe df that had the ID column value in it.

```
node_id_2=pd.DataFrame(data=node_id)

node_id_2.rename(columns={0: 'node_id'}, inplace=True)

df_out = pd.merge(df,node_id_2,how = 'left',left_index = True, right_index = True)

import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

q2 = """SELECT count(distinct ID),node_id FROM df_out 
group by node_id"""

x=ps.sqldf(q2, locals())
```

The x gives me a list of the unique ID values in each leaf node and I just manually plot these in image file containing the decision tree plot by matching on the node ids using an image editing tool.

I still don't get a count of ID values in each split, only the unique ID values that end up in each leaf node.